# How do we know what is an auspicious quality of the Lord?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, brahman, brahma-sutras

According to Sri Vaishnavism, Brahman is full of "auspicious" qualities.

For example, in Ramanujacharya's [commentary](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48037.htm) on the Brahma Sutras, he says:

> The conclusion therefore is that texts such as 'That from whence these beings are born' etc. do convey valid instruction as to the existence of Brahman, i.e. that being which is the sole cause of the world, **is free from all shadow of imperfection, comprises within itself all auspicious qualities, such as omniscience and so on, and is of the nature of supreme bliss.**--Here terminates the adhikarana of 'connexion'.

But isn't what is considered "auspicious" and "perfect" a matter of opinion?

For example, some people do not think omniscience is a desirable or auspicious quality. Other people also think that infinite bliss is not a desirable or auspicious quality.

I personally agree that these are desirable and auspicious qualities, but others may not.

Compassion and mercy is another one of Brahman's auspicious qualities. But again, there are many people who consider these bad qualities.

Comment: Free will is what let's you decide what's auspicious and what's not!

Comment: There's nothing that isnt auspicious for Paramatma. Paramatma himself is auspicious, everywhere, perfect in his own nature etc....lke this he has infinite qualities which are auspicious

Comment: you can get them vishnushashranama that describes vishnu aspusious qualities in limited no.. which human can grasp, for example vishnu, one which resides inside everything.. and one which is outside every thing.. and so no.. vis iti anu one which controls everything.. each word in vishnu sashranama gives 100 meaning according to sriman madvacharya